# Problems decorating an instance method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I'm having a difficult problem with decorating an instance method in ES6. I'm having no problem decorating the method, but it seems as though it is stuck with a single state of the instance of the class. Here is what I'm dealing with specifically:

```
class Test {
    init() {
        this.foo = 'bar';
    }

    @decorator
    decoratedMethod() {
        console.log(this.foo); // undefined
    }
}

let test = new Test();
test.init();
test.decoratedMethod();

function decorator(target, name, descriptor) {
     let fn = target[ name ].bind(target, 'a', 'b');
     return fn;
}
```

I realize that the code above is doing exactly what it should be, but if I want to have access to `foo` and other properties added to the scope how can I decorate `decoratedMethod` and still bind new function properties?

Comment: You are decorating a *prototype* method here - the `target` is `Test.prototype`, and there's only one of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method decorators run once at class declaration time, not when the class is instantiated. That means the `target` in your example is `Test.prototype`, not an instance. So your example is essentially:

```
class Test {
  init() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }

  decoratedMethod() {
    console.log(this.foo); // undefined
  }
}

Test.prototype.decoratedMethod = 
    Test.prototype.decoratedMethod.bind(Test.prototype, 'a', 'b');
```

That should make it clear why your code is failing. The object you are binding has no `foo` property, only the instance does.

If you want your decorator to be processed for each instance, things get more complicated and you'd need to make the bind happen after the instance is created. One approach to that would be

```
function decorator(target, name, descriptor){
  const {value} = descriptor;
  delete descriptor.value;
  delete descriptor.writable;
  descriptor.get = function(){
    // Create an instance of the bound function for the instance.
    // And set an instance property to override the property
    // from the object prototype.
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
      enumerable: descriptor.enumerable,
      configurable: descriptor.configurable,
      value: value.bind(this, 'a', 'b'),
    });

    return this[name];
  };
}
```

Comment: Using this, if you subclass the class, the child method is replaced entirely by the parent.

Comment: I tried adding a "set" clause, so that the function is always properly set, but I'm getting an error off of that as well